# Hibernate Session saveOrUpdate does not update

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am using hibernate with derby. I use the following pattern to save my objects:

```
Session session = null
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    session = mySessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    MyPersistentType obj = session.load(MyPersistentType.class, id);
    obj.setAttribute(attr);
    session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    tx.commit();
    log.debug("Committed");
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
} finally {
    if (session != null) session.close();
}
```

In the above, I am certain flushMode is AUTO, my log statement prints, and the logs show that JDBC connection have been committed, with the new attribute I have set to my object. However the next time I fetch the object from the DB (and it happens split second later), the object being fetched has the original value, not the newly set one.

About my MyPersistentType:

- It has an auto generated Long id
- It does not have version number, all updates to it are encapsulated within a transaction
- It is annotated. I do not use mapping, I use annotations.

All I can think of is that some caching has gone awry, except I do not even use any cache. Saving the object for the first time (using a different session object, in the same manner as above) works fine. It is the updates that I am having problem with. BTW, I did try session.flush() (no good reason really, just for completeness), session.merge() (even though the object is attached) etc. None worked. So, my question(s) are:

- Could it still be some caching problem?
- If so can I force this query to hit the disk each time

Or if anything else you can think of. I am completely stumped.

Edit1: After the above sequence gets executed, I stopped the service and connected to the DB using IJ. Doing select on the said table, I saw that the table was not modified, even though the commit did not fail. Also, the log shows the following lines:

```
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
```

In other words, the commit did succeed, but the session did not realize the object was modified. So the question becomes, how can I tell the session that there is a dirty object in it. I thought this should be automatic, but clearly it is not happening in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from log, have you checked your table with data? When you update the record, is it reflected in the dB?

Comment: No I didn't. Perhaps I should, but I am using derby in embedded mode, meaning either the application or ij can connect to it, not both. Thanks.

Comment: You can start your Derby with the startNetworkServer.bat file.  That way, more than one connection is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are having managed object (obj) no need to call save / saveupdate. hibernate will recognize changes and call updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should try 
`MyPersistentType obj = session.get(MyPersistentType.class, id);`
instead of `session.load();`
session.load sometimes returns a proxy object (lazy initialized).